# onClick replace previous items of state by using key to iterate over data and replace by new data in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this data in state and mapping through it to generate new list items on click I want to update the same card with nested data using the key I'm storing as the current directory and replace the previous values with new ones after clicking the list item.

```
{
      directory_Level_2__first: [
            {
              directory_Level_3__first: [
                "some name",
                "some other name",
                "some other name than the other"
              ]
            },
            {
              directory_Level_3__second: [
                "some name",
                "some other name",
                "some other name than the other"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

```
// state

  constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data : Data,
            currentDirectory : '',
            directories : []
        }
    }
```

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <List component="nav" className={classes.root} aria-label="mailbox folders">
            {
                this.state.data.map((item,i) => 
                    <ListItem button divider key={i} onClick={this.handleClick}>
             <ListItemText primary={ Object.keys(item)} onClick={this.handleDirectory}/>
                    </ListItem>
                    )
            }
        </List>
    )
}
```

```
 handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ currentDirectory : e.currentTarget.textContent });
    }

    handleDirectory = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

want to make use of this handle directory function to replace previous values with new onse on the list item